# Spark-Shell: Howto define JAR loading order

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Running spark-shell locally + define classpath to some 3rd party JARs:

```
$ spark-shell --driver-class-path /Myproject/LIB/*
```

Within the shell, I typed

```
scala> import com.google.common.collect.Lists
<console>:19: error: object collect is not a member of package com.google.common
   import com.google.common.collect.Lists
                            ^
```

I suppose Spark has loaded first /usr/local/spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/**spark-assembly-1.4.0-hadoop2.6.0.jar** which doesn't contain the com.google.common.collect package.

/Myproject/LIB/ contains **google-collections-1.0.jar** and has the com.google.common.collect. However, this jar seems to be ignored.

**Question**: How to tell spark-shell to load the JARs in --driver-class-path before those in spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/ ?

**ANSWER**: combining hints from Sathish and Holden comments
`--jars` must be used instead of `--driver-class-path`. All jar files must be specified. The jars must be comma-delimited, no space (as per `spark-shell --help`)

```
$ spark-shell --jars $(echo ./Myproject/LIB/*.jar | tr ' ' ',')
```

Comment: Try using the --jar option as follows, spark-shell --jar /Myproject/LIB/google-collections-1.0.jar

Comment: @Sathish --jars is indeed the solution but it's quite long to type as all jars must be specified. Thanks to Holden trick below which allows to shorten the syntax. Initial questions has been edited to include the answer. Thx.

Answer (score 4):

The driver class path flag needs to be comma separated. So ,based on [Setting multiple jars in java classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/219585/setting-multiple-jars-in-java-classpath) , we can try `spark-shell --driver-class-path $(echo ./Myproject/LIB/*.jar | tr ' ' ',')`

Comment: Thanks for the tricks using `$(echo ./Myproject/LIB/*.jar | tr ' ' ':')` The separator must actually be a comma. I have edited my initial question to include the answer.