# How to run spark shell with *local* packages?

Tags: maven, apache-spark, package

The page here (http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html) indicates packages can be included when the shell is launched via:

```
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-shell --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.4.0
```

What is the syntax for including local packages (that are downloaded manually say)? Something to do with Maven coords?

Comment: You mean the packages are already locally available in the master/workers?

Comment: Yes, I am thinking of a kind of global consistently mounted file system. I should have mentioned that. So all workers see the same directory.

Comment: For anyone reading this now, spark-csv has now been inlined into spark 2.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the jars are present on the master/workers, you simply need to specify them on the classpath in spark-submit:

```
spark-shell \
spark.driver.extraClassPath="/path/to/jar/spark-csv_2.11.jar" \
spark.executor.extraClassPath="spark-csv_2.11.jar"
```

If the jars are *only present in the Master*, and you want them to be sent to the worker (only works for client mode), you can add the `--jars` flag:

```
spark-shell \
spark.driver.extraClassPath="/path/to/jar/spark-csv_2.11.jar" \
spark.executor.extraClassPath="spark-csv_2.11.jar" \
--jars "/path/to/jar/jary.jar:/path/to/other/other.jar"
```

For a more elaborated answer see [Add jars to a Spark Job - spark-submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37132559/add-jars-to-a-spark-job-spark-submit/37348234#37348234)

Answer (score 2):

Please use:

> ./spark-shell --jars *my_jars_to_be_included*

There is a open question related to this: Please check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30814941/spark-shell-howto-define-jar-loading-order) out.

Comment: it should be `--jars` not `--jar`