# Copying avro jars into docker jars directory

Tags: docker, apache-spark, copy-paste, avro, spark-avro

I'm learning spark I'd like to use an avro data file as avro is external to spark. I've downloaded the jar. But my problem is how to copy it into that specific place 'jars dir' into my container? 
[image]
I've read relative post here but I do not understand.

I've see also this command below from spark main website but I think I need the jar file copied before running it.

```
./bin/spark-shell --packages org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.XX:X.X.X ...
```

What I tried is

```
docker cp /Users/username/Downloads/spark-avro_2.11-2.4.5.jar docker-spark_master_1:/jars
```

but it's not working.
thanks in advance

nb: I'm running spark 2.4 container with worker and master.

Comment: The `jars` directory is under `/usr/spark-2.4.1`.  Your destination for cp should be `docker-spark_master_1:/usr/spark-2.4.1/jars/`. Still, the command you tried should have created a file called `jars` under `/`. That did not happen?

Comment: Yes yes I see jars in root /..

Comment: spark_master_1 should be the name of master

Comment: `docker-spark_master_1` is the name of the container. The syntax is `container_name:destination`

Comment: Merci, Thanks it worked

Comment: Will update it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting [`docker cp` Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/#extended-description),

> `docker cp SRC_PATH CONTAINER:DEST_PATH`
>
> If `SRC_PATH` specifies a file and `DEST_PATH` does not exist then the
>   file is saved to a file created at `DEST_PATH`

From the command you tried,

The destination path `/jars` does not exist in the container since the actual destination should have been `/usr/spark-2.4.1/jars/`. Thus the jar was copied to the container with the name `jars` under the root (`/`) directory.

Try this command instead to add the jar to spark jars,

```
docker cp /Users/username/Downloads/spark-avro_2.11-2.4.5.jar docker-spark_master_1:/usr/spark-2.4.1/jars/
```

Comment: One quetion how to make this command works?
./bin/spark-shell --packages org.apache.spark:spark-avro_x.x.:xxx

Comment: Use `--jars <path-of-the-avro-jar>` instead of `--packages ...`. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37643831/how-to-run-spark-shell-with-local-packages).